# Windows batch: set && echo does not work

Tags: windows, batch-file, syntax

This is a Windows cmd.exe question. Trying to set a variable and then using && to include another command referencing that variable in one command line does not work. The variable is not set until the next line is processed.

Steps to reproduce:

```
set X=1 && echo %X%
%X%

echo %X%
1

set X=2 && echo %X%
1

echo %X%
2
```

Is there a way to make this work as expected?

Comment: There is no need whatsoever for the two ampersands. A case could be made for one, but I'd still say that the `echo` command should just be placed on the next line.

Comment: If "This is a Windows batch file question", why your examples are taken from the command line? The first line show a different output _in a Batch file_. You may use: `set X=1 && call echo %%X%%` See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970348/how-to-realize-an-assignment-within-the-if-block/9970460#9970460)

Answer (score 1):

Make the first line: [`setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) then

```
set X=I_AM_ECHOED && echo !X!
echo !X!
```

Would print

```
I_AM_ECHOED
I_AM_ECHOED
```

Comment: Well no, thats the command line, not a batch file. Quite different.

Comment: setlocal enabledelayedexpansion&&set X=FOO && echo !Z!  Result: !Z!